# stellar-core on CentOS 7 - systemd issue

Tags: stellar-core

I run stellar-core on CentOS7.

When I run by using command line, everything is fine, and I can create account.

However, when I run it on systemd, I always encounter timeout failure

The user I use to run command line and systemd is same.

Creating account...
Timeout. Please resubmit your transaction to receive submission status. More info: https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/errors/timeout.html
org.stellar.sdk.responses.SubmitTransactionTimeoutResponseException: Timeout. Please resubmit your transaction to receive submission status. More info: https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/errors/timeout.html
    at org.stellar.sdk.Server.submitTransaction(Server.java:189)
    at com.singcloud.stellar.CreateAccount.main(CreateAccount.java:78)

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running? What's the output when you run `journalctl -u`?